# How to retrieve data from server and save into a file in [Objective-C] iPhone programming?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, nsdata

I've saved the contents of server into a NSData. How do I copy the contents of NSData into a file.

Comment: If possible can you please give me some examples of initWithData of UIImage in iPhone?

Comment: Example? Sure: `[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [NSData writeToFile:atomically:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:atomically:) method. Just pass in the filename and it will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *imagelist = Data;

NSData *yourimageFileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagelist]];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);


NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *yourFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:reString];

[yourimageFileData writeToFile:yourFilePath atomically:YES];
```